# Hibernate/Spring Custom Validations w/ Autowired repository

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-validator, customvalidator

I am building a custom constraint validator, and keep getting `HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.]`

The weird part is that the `findById` method returns and prints the correct data on the console, but errors out with above error. How can I make this not have an error?

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@Validated
public class invitecontroller {

    @PostMapping("/v1/invite")
    public void invite(@Valid @RequestBody invite invite){
    }

}
```

```
@inviteconstraints
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class invite {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long inviteid;

    private String type;
    private Long propertyid;
    private Date moveindate;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "inviteid")
    private List<applicant> applicants;

}
```

```
public class inviteconstraint implements ConstraintValidator<inviteconstraints, invite> {
  
    @Autowired propertyrepository propertyrepository;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(invite invite, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        
       
        property property = propertyrepository.findById(1L).get();  

        ^^^ **Error Happens Here** ^^^


        return true;
    }

    @Override 
    public void initialize(inviteconstraints constraintannotation) {
    }

}
```

```
@Target(  { ElementType.TYPE } )  
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)  
@Constraint(validatedBy = inviteconstraint.class)
public @interface inviteconstraints {
 
    public String message() default "Validator Failed"; 
    public Class<?>[] groups() default {};  
    public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {}; 
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Autowiring doesn't work in this case hence you are getting error at this (propertyRepository)point.
In order to make the Autowiring work you need to make another configuration. After using this the Autowiring will happen successfully.

```
@Component
public class HibernateValidatorCustomizer implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    private final ObjectProvider<Validator> provider;

    public HibernateValidatorCustomizer(ObjectProvider<Validator> provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        Validator validator = provider.getIfUnique();
        if (validator != null) {
            hibernateProperties.put("javax.persistence.validation.factory", validator);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird, worked like a charm. Just had to pop this into another file and add the imports for everything and things seem to be working. I just don't understand what it's doing.